# Find a *.txt file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, find

I want to write a script that search if a directory contains a `*.txt` file.

I've written this script but it doesn't work. Can someone help me to correct it?

```
extension = .txt
for file in /tmp/test12072022/*
do
    echo  $file
    if [ -e /tmp/test12072022/$file$extension ]
    then
        echo "the .txt file existe"
    else
        echo "the .txt file not existe "
    fi
done
```

Comment: What does the `echo $file` line print? ... And what would the `/tmp/test12072022/$file$extension` string evaluate to?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$file` already contains the file name with its extension and path information. That should be clear with `echo $file`. Finding files is however easier with `find`:

```
find /tmp/test12072022/ -name '*.txt' -print -quit
```

If you don't want to search subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1`. You can also store the results in a variable.

```
found=$(find /tmp/test12072022/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print -quit)
```